# Why below code is not working as expected?

Tags: perl

I have below code to match particular keyword from file, Please note that particular keyword is present in that file. (Verified)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $fname="sample.txt";
my @o_msg_rx;

my $tempStr='=?UTF-8?B?U2Now4PCtm5l?=\, Ma ';

push @o_msg_rx, $tempStr;

foreach my $rx_temp (@o_msg_rx) {
        print "rx_temp = $rx_temp\n";
}

my @msg_arr;
open MM, '<', $fname;
chomp(@msg_arr = (<MM>));
close MM;

my (%o_msg_rx, %msg_anti_rx);
foreach my $rx (@o_msg_rx){
        ($rx =~ s/^!// ? $msg_anti_rx{$rx} : $o_msg_rx{$rx}) = 0 if $rx;
        print "rx = \t$rx\n";
        print "o_msg_rx_rx = \t$o_msg_rx{$rx}\n";
}
if(@msg_arr) {
        foreach my $rx (keys %o_msg_rx) {
                $o_msg_rx{$rx} = 1 if grep (/$rx/i, @msg_arr);
        }
}

my $regex_ok = (! scalar grep (! $o_msg_rx{$_}, keys %o_msg_rx));

print "regex_ok = $regex_ok\n";
```

I am attaching few lines from the file for clarification.

```
# Step: 23    14:48:52
#  
# var: expect-count='1'
# var: msg-rx=""=?UTF-8?B?U2Now4PCtm5l?=\, Maik ""
# etc etc etc
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you intend for `$tempStr` to be interpreted as a regular expression? If so, then you should know that the `?` is a regular expression operator and will not literally match a `?` in the target string.

Also, it has a space after `Ma` but your sample file has `Maik` so that part won't match.

These changes will produce a different result:

```
my $tempStr='=?UTF-8?B?U2Now4PCtm5l?=\, Ma'; # remove the extra space

grep (/\Q$rx/i, @msg_arr); # Add \Q to match the literal string $tempStr in regexp
```

Or you could make `$tempStr` a real regexp from the start:

```
my $tempStr=qr/=\?UTF-8\?B\?U2Now4PCtm5l\?=\\, Ma/;
```

Or you could leave it as a string but put it in regexp syntax (needs an extra doubling of the double backslash, very ugly):

```
my $tempStr='=\?UTF-8\?B\?U2Now4PCtm5l\?=\\\\, Ma';
```

Comment: Thanks, your first solutions works properly but unfortunately I can not go for it as it impacts others changes also, 2nd and 3rd solution doesn't work. Really appreciate your effort, Can you please help in getting the solution from 2nd or 3rd method ?

Comment: Don't tell me "doesn't work". I test things before I post them. Your entire original program, with that one line changed, does work (prints `regex_ok = 1`).